# Dynamically update a variable between rows in R/dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, dynamic, lag

I have data from multiple games of the game Battleships. It looks something like this:

```
> data.frame(game=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2),
  position=c(2,4,3,1,1,2,3,4),
  hit=c(0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0))

  game position hit
1    1        2   0
2    1        4   0
3    1        3   1
4    1        1   0
5    2        1   1
6    2        2   0
7    2        3   0
8    2        4   0
```

Each row is one move of a player: position is the square number and hit indicates whether they hit a ship or not.
I want to create an additional row that would indicate the state of the board before each move. It should look something like this:

```
  game position hit board_state
1    1        2   0 [NA,NA,NA,NA]
2    1        4   0 [NA,0,NA,NA]
3    1        3   1 [NA,0,NA,0]
4    1        1   0 [NA,0,1,0]
5    2        1   1 [NA,NA,NA,NA]
6    2        2   0 [1,NA,NA,NA]
7    2        3   0 [1,0,NA,NA]
8    2        4   0 [1,0,0,NA]
```

So the board state is updated based on the position and outcome of the last step.

What I find challenging here is that the definition of `board_state` on row r depends on its state on row r-1, and lag is not useful here because it's within the same column. I hope this is clear.

Any ideas for how to implement this? Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach using `dplyr` and `tidyr`. First, I add a column to track which turn we're on within each game. (This will help with a later step when we pivot wide.) Then I "complete" the table to have a row for every position and every turn within each game. Then we can "fill" down and shift back one step so that each position reflects its past history. Finally we can group by game and turn and generate a "board_position" summary that concatenates the "hit" values for each position.

```
library(dplyr); library(tidyr)
df %>%
  group_by(game) %>%
  mutate(turn = row_number()) %>%
  complete(game, position, turn) %>%
  group_by(game, position) %>%
  fill(hit) %>%
  mutate(hit = lag(hit)) %>%
  group_by(game, turn) %>%
  summarize(board_state = paste(hit, collapse = ", "), .groups = "drop")
```

Result

```
# A tibble: 8 × 3
   game  turn board_state   
  <dbl> <int> <chr>         
1     1     1 NA, NA, NA, NA
2     1     2 NA, 0, NA, NA 
3     1     3 NA, 0, NA, 0  
4     1     4 NA, 0, 1, 0   
5     2     1 NA, NA, NA, NA
6     2     2 1, NA, NA, NA 
7     2     3 1, 0, NA, NA  
8     2     4 1, 0, 0, NA
```

Comment: Thanks Jon, this is great! Two questions: first, what in this code guarantees that the first entry in board state corresponds to position 1? And second, is it possible to have board_state as a list, rather than a string?

Comment: I am presuming above that your full data set uses all the positions, and so the `complete` step will make rows for all the existing positions. If this is not the case you could edit that line to `complete(game, position = 1:4, turn) %>%` to explicitly include positions 1,2,3,4 for every game and turn.  [I'll try to come back to the "list" question later.]

Comment: I might be doing something wrong with applying this to my own dataset or maybe it's the actual size of my dataset (25 positions, 1000 games, and other columns like RT etc), but I'm getting an error message  ('r: cannot allocate vector of size 105.7 Mb'). I wonder if a for loop over rows would not actually be simpler here?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with the following solution:

```
create_board_states <- function(positions,hits) {
  
  board_state = rep(NA,4)
  board_states = c();
  for (p in seq_along(positions)) {
    board_states = c(board_states, paste(board_state,collapse=','));
    board_state[positions[p]]=hits[p];
  }
  
  return(board_states)
}

df %>% 
  group_by(game) %>% 
  summarise(board_state=create_board_states(position,hit)) %>% 
  mutate(board_state=as.list(strsplit(board_state,',')))
```